# RavenDB - Transformers have odd behaviors

Tags: ravendb

In an attempt to utilize `RavenDB` and perform a transformer on a query, I am getting a bit of a strange behavior.

Assuming a class `Member`, that is rather long and verbose...

```
class Member {
   // ...
   // Lots of properties, methods
}
```

I just want to get a more lightweight result of them. So I declare a smaller class.

```
public class MiniMember {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And attempt to query it with an `AbstractTransformerCreationTask<T>`.

```
public class MemberByNameList : AbstractTransformerCreationTask<Member> {
    public MemberByNameList() {
        TransformResults = members => from member in members
                                     select new MiniMember {
                                         Id = member.Id,
                                         Name = member.Name
                                     };
    }
}
```

This works fine on the server side Studio UI, but when I attempt to do this in my `.NET` code, I get problems.

```
        var members = DocumentSession
            .Query<Member>()
            .TransformWith<Indexes.MemberByNameList, MiniMember>()
            .Take(512)
            .ToList();
```

I am told that `Member` cannot be cast to class `MiniMember`.

I have followed the examples on the RavenDB documentation very closely, and still receive this result, so I am extremely confused about this.

## [RavenDB Documentation on Result Transformers](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/results-transformation/result-transformers)

Answer (score 8):

I tried your code and it worked for me.  There are a couple of things I can see though where you might be getting confused.

- The docs aren't clear that you must *register* your transformers.  If you didn't do this, makes sure that you use `documentStore.ExecuteTransformer` before you try to use your transformer.

  However, if you are somewhere calling `IndexCreation.CreateIndexes` to scan for all indexes to create, it will pick up transformers as well.  So then there would be no need to register it again.
- The name you gave your transformer, `MemberByNameList` is the convention one might use for an index.  You might have an index called that - I see you have `Indexes.MemberByNameList` in your query.

  If you're passing an index instead of the transformer, that won't work.  You should name your transformers in a way that describes what they transform.  Perhaps `MiniMemberTransformer` would work better.

  Of course, Raven could care less what you name it, but that would prevent you from mistaking it for an index.

Here is [a complete test](https://gist.github.com/mj1856/6746666) showing how this is should be working.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot! The official docs I've seen don't mention registering the transformers. They just show the transformer code and the query that uses them. Argh.